# Filling repetitive shapes inside an object

Tags: shapes

[image]

First of all, I got this picture from one of Downgraf's designs  on Pinterest, and I am very interested in creating a design similar to this. I want to know what it's called and how it's made with less difficulty. Thank your in advance.

Comment: This might help? http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/79936/distribute-objects-optimaly

Comment: Hello Alexis. Please see our [style identification requirements](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2931/52050) and edit your post to match. Otherwise your question may be closed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello a simple google search did the job, look here for a tutorial on the following effect.

http://vectorboom.com/load/tips/techniques/how_to_distribute_shapes_within_another_shape_in_illustrator/16-1-0-470

Goodluck.

Comment: As it stands, this is a link-only answer. Please [edit] it to make it work without the link.

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be https://svgnest.com/, an open source tool designed for CNC. It's a browser-based vector nesting tool.
You can work with SVG. Check out the Git repo too here https://github.com/Jack000/SVGnest

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design SE. Please note that if you can post the same answer to several questions, something is likely going wrong. Either the answer doesn’t fit to all questions or the questions are duplicates of each other. In your case, most of the questions are duplicates and your answer fails to elaborate how the tool you are proposing should be applied to the problem in question. Please [edit] or delete your answers to account for this.